# Laravel model output customize

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a column named "name" in my database table hold JSON value like that:

```
{"en":"Morocco","ar":"المغرب"}
```

I want to access this value automatically depending on the current language by just writing: `$country->name` on my view, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor). In your Country Eloquent Model, add this:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) {
    $name = json_decode($value, true);
    return $name[app()->getLocale()];
}
```